# How to dynamically create tables in another database of the same server using MySQL Procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

There is a circumstance that I should separate some tables by different company ids. Each company has a individual database and the table replicas. I need to create database and copy tables using one MySQL Procedure when adding a company. Just like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE new_db (IN project_id INT) 
BEGIN
    DECLARE tempsql VARCHAR(500);
    SET tempsql = CONCAT('CREATE DATABASE crawl_data_p', project_id);
    PREPARE stmt FROM tempsql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    -- how to change database here? ? ? ? ? ?
```

Now I wanna create tables in the database I created just now, but cannot change the database dynamically. I searched it in google but in vain. Using `PREPARE` to switch database is invalid. So how can I copy tables to the new database?

Comment: I don't think you need to switch data base just qualify the create statement with the target db name

Comment: just like: create dbname.tablename? @P.Salmon

Comment: 'The table name can be specified as db_name.tbl_name to create the table in a specific database.' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html